# How to use mysqlimport to read in result of mysqldump --databases

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have successfully dumped an entire MySQL database using

```
mysqldump --databases
```

generating a nice .txt file. However, I can't see how to read the whole file back into MySQL in one go; mysqlimport seems to want just one table at a time.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you've generated some file *(say `db-dump.sql`)* with `mysqldump`, you can import it to your other database with the `mysql` command :

```
mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX --host=YOUR_HOST DATABASE_NAME < db-dump.sql
```

And, if you don't want the password to appear in a command, you can use :

```
mysql --user=XXX -p --host=YOUR_HOST DATABASE_NAME < db-dump.sql
```

As a sidenote, if you want to copy one DB to another one, you don't need to use a file, and can just directly pipe the output of `mysqldump` to `mysql` :

```
mysqldump --user=XXX --password=XXX --host=SOURCE_HOST SOURCE_DB | mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX --host=DESTINATION_HOST DESTINATION_DB
```

*(It should even be faster, as you're not using a temporary file that resides on disk)*

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN I was trying to do the same thing and didn't have success. Here is my thread explaining the problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160879/importing-sql-file-in-mysql-no-errors?noredirect=1#comment309278_160879

Answer (score 14):

I do this frequently:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > dump.sql
```

To load:

```
mysql -u username -p  targetdatabasename < dump.sql
```

Switch `-p` instructs the database to prompt you to enter the password for the user `username` once the command launches.

Your question is probably duplicate though.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use 'source' from within the mysql client:

```
source dumpfile.sql
```

Or supply directly from command line:

```
mysql -u user -p password database < source dumpfile.sql
```

This is because the result of mysqldump is just a SQL file that can be run via mysql as usual.