# Restoring mysql dump text file to database

Tags: mysql

I am working with analysing big data using opencl. I got the data in mysql dump text file (dump.txt). I want to restore the data into mysql database. Then I can connect to the database and do the other stuff related to parallel programming to analysis big data.

I went through some tutorials and questions related this. I found a related question here. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298176/how-to-use-mysqlimport-to-read-in-result-of-mysqldump-databases). But there they mentioned the way to restore .sql dump file. what can we do for dump text files?

Abstract part of my dump text file is here

> "94723605719","435035","2013-06-01 23:51:36","2013-06-01","2013","6","1","7","22
>   ","23","51","36","1","202","-1002409728","1005823215","50000.000",\N,"1613003749
>   10","50026.000","226","0","0","94723605719","34399725","0","0","0",\N
>   "94722616878","435014","2013-06-01 23:51:52","2013-06-01","2013","6","1","7","22
>   ","23","51","52","1","202","-1002099361","1005511506","50000.000",\N,"1613002394
>   31","50127.000","157","0","0","94722616878","34438596","0","0","0",\N
>   "94726556777","435022","2013-06-01 23:51:52","2013-06-01","2013","6","1","7","22
>   ","23","51","52","1","202","-1002496570","1005910182","50000.000",\N,"1614002967
>   42","61046.000","226","0","0","94726556777","34399744","0","0","0",\N

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 'real' dump, then you can use:

```
mysql -u root -p -h local host < your_dump.sql
```

That said, your example listed in the question seems to hint that you just have the values in a CSV file, in which case you need to first create the table and then load the data into it:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file.txt' 
 INTO TABLE your_table 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

See MySQL manual for [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful.I used following query. **LOAD DATA INFILE 'source_event_reload.txt' INTO TABLE source_event_reload FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\N\n' STARTING BY '';** But I could only restore first row of the database. Can you please find where I am fault. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"` would probably be correct. `"\N"` stands for null while `"\n"` is used for linefeed. You should also drop the `STARTING BY` as that's probably irrelevant.

Comment: When I remove '\N', It gives error of **ERROR 1262 (01000): Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns**. Even when I remove STARTING BY, It works as previous(Update one row only). Any suggestion please.

Comment: I'm not sure if your example is fully legible, but it seems that you have 29 fields to load. Is that correct? Does your input field have linefeed (`\n`) as row terminator?

Comment: It's actually 28 fields. Every row start in newline.

Comment: Well, your sample data has 29 fields so that's probably your problem right there ;) Try to add extra field and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: You are correct.I didn't include the last /N character. Now I am using **load data infile 'source_event_reload.txt' into table source_event_reload fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';** It has been uploading for 1.30 hours. I'm using myphpadmin. It shows 2,298,481 row has been uploaded. But problem is I couldn't see the data in phpmydamin. Y is that?

Comment: When I use **SELECT* FROM source_event_reload LIMIT 0,30** , It says Empty set.

Comment: There could be several reasons for slowness. Indexes might be one. What table type do you use? In case of InnoDB you could do `SET unique_checks=0; SET foreign_key_checks=0;` if you know that your data doesn't violate any Unique or Foreign key constraints. Use `ALTER TABLE source_event_reload DISABLED KEYS;` with MyISAM table. Of course you need to enable the keys after you have loaded your data.

Comment: Thanks.My dataset has around 160000000 lines. (I found this using wc -l file.txt). First I loaded data without using this settings. It couldn't load within a day also. I dropped that approach. Now I am using queries you mentioned. I used **SET autocommit=0;SET unique_checks=0;SET foreign_key_checks=0;** and edited /etc/my.cnf **innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2400M** to increase the memory size used by mysql. It works better than before. About 6000000 rows have been updated within 2 hours. Is it resonable? or Is there any way to increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to migrate MySql databases and the best way for me is like this:

Export Database(backup):

```
mysqldump -u root -p [database_name] >  [dump_filename].sql
```

Import Database:

```
mysql -u root -p [database_name] < [dump_filename].sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database you want to restore doesn't already exist, you need to create it first.

On the command-line, if you're in the same directory that contains the dumped file, use these commands (with appropriate substitutions):

```
C:\> mysql -u root -p

mysql> create database mydb;
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> source db_backup.dump;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.6/en/using-mysqldump.html

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Database_dump_and_restore_examples