# How to mysqlimport a local export to remote mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I have a local mysql dump that I want to copy-insert into a remote db:

```
mysqlimport --host=192.168.xxx.xxx --user=username --password=password remote_table /tmp/export.txt
```

Result:
`mysqlimport: Error: 1290, The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`

So how can I tell my remote mysql server to accept imports from remote machine?

Comment: Is the `export.txt` already on the same server where your DB is? Should be as simple as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2298326/2008111

Comment: No the  `export.txt` is on my local machine, and I want to "pipe" this file into the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

i) take mysql dump as follows

**mysqldump -u user -p db-name > db-name.out**

ii) Copy db-name.out file using sftp/ssh to remote MySQL server:

**scp db-name.out user@remote.box.com:/remoteBoxDirectory**

iii)Restore database at remote server (login over ssh):

**mysql -u user -p db-name < db-name.out**
or
**mysql -u user -p 'password' db-name < db-name.out**